# Creating tuples from two vectors

Tags: r

If I have two vectors of the same length `A<-c(5,10)` and `B<-c(7,13)` how can I easily turn these two vectors into a single tuple vector i. e. `c((5,7),(7,13))`?

Comment: The structure you define is a list in R. A list is a generic vector, where each element can be any type of R object. In this case you want a list where each element is a vector of length two, containing a tuple.

Comment: You need to clarify your question, since `c(A,B)` "works".  I.e. what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Joshua - a potential downfall of that approach is that there's nothing strucutural identifying which numbers are part of a tuple.

Comment: @MattParker: I completely agree, but I would rather the OP clarify their needs than guess.  A list is more like a tuple in other languages (Python) but it could be much slower than using a matrix, depending on what the OP is doing.

Comment: The original question had `c((5,7),(7,13))` and was "corrected" to `c((5,10),(7,13))` but I think it should have been corrected to `c((5,7),(10,13))`. @Ellipsis, please verify.

Comment: Folks would be less confused if you had three output pairs, instead of two.  Then the way you want the output organized would be clearer and less likely to be misread.

Comment: I'm guessing that you actually want your "tuples" (a python syntax not relevant to R) in order to do something with them.  I'm guessing that what you want to accomplish is not best accomplished using the structure you're asking for but something else.  If you rewrote your question talking about what you want to accomplish as an end result instead of asking for (essentially) an incompatible data type, you'll get much more useful help.  If you want an incompatible data type you're probably programming in a python style that's inefficient as well.

Comment: I've put the original back - was presuming too much. Hopefully the OP will clarify what output they do actually want. I assumed the equivalent of `list(A,B)`, but @Brian suggests another option. Whatever is required, the output shown in the original is wrong and needs fixing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Others have mentioned lists. I see other possibilities:

```
cbind(A, B)  # makes a column-major  2x2-"vector"
rbind(A, B)  # an row major 2x2-"vector" which could also be added to an array with `abind`
```

It is also possible to preserve their "origins"

```
AB <- cbind(A=A, B=B)
array(c(AB,AB+10), c(2,2,2) )
, , 1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]   10   13
, , 2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   15   17
[2,]   20   23

> abind( array(c(AB,AB+10), c(2,2,2) ), AB+20)
, , 1
      A  B
[1,]  5  7
[2,] 10 13

, , 2
      A  B
[1,] 15 17
[2,] 20 23

, , 3
      A  B
[1,] 25 27
[2,] 30 33
```

Comment: Also consider data.frame(A=A, B=B)

Answer (score 11):

Your tuple vector `c((5,7),(7,13))` is not valid syntax.  However, your phrasing makes me think you are thinking of something like python's `zip`.  How do you want your tuples represented in R?  R has a heterogeneous (recursive) type `list` and a homogenous type `vector`; there are no scalar types (that is, types that just hold a single value), just vectors of length 1 (somewhat an oversimplification).

If you want your tuples to be rows of a matrix (all the same type, which they are here):

```
rbind(A,B)
```

If you want a list of vectors

```
mapply(c, A, B, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

If you want a list of lists (which is what you would need if `A` and `B` are not the same type)

```
mapply(list, A, B, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Putting this all together:

```
> A<-c(5,10)
> B<-c(7,13)
> 
> cbind(A,B)
      A  B
[1,]  5  7
[2,] 10 13
> mapply(c, A, B, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] 5 7

[[2]]
[1] 10 13

> mapply(list, A, B, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 5

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 7


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 13
```

Comment: R does have something called atomic types (or modes).  See `?atomic`.  I think I know what you mean (scalar values), but others may be more confused.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich You are right that "atomic" was not the best choice of words since it does have a specific meaning in R.  The idea I was trying to get at was that there is no type that holds _only_ a single value.  If you have a suggestion of a better way to phrase that, I would be happy to consider it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not certain this is exactly what you're looking for, but:

`list(A, B)`

which gives you a structure like this:

```
> str(list(A, B))
List of 2
 $ : num [1:2] 5 10
 $ : num [1:2] 7 13
```

and is literally represented like this:

> dput(list(A, B))
>   list(c(5, 10), c(7, 13))

... which is about as close to the suggested end result as you can get, I think.

A list in R is essentially a vector of whatever you want it to be.

If that isn't what you're looking for, it might be helpful if you could expand on what exactly you'd like to do with this vector.

Comment: +1 `list()` certainly seems like the most suitable object type to use.

Comment: @Matt, I think it's rotated from what he wants - rows for columns and vice versa.  Not sure, though!

Comment: @Ed The `str()` bit is just an easy-to-read representation - the list itself doesn't have rows or columns at all, really.  It's literally a vector containing the tuples.  For iterating over tuples, lists are definitely the way to go.  Not sure what the application is here, though.

Comment: @Matt - sorry, I'll spell it out. I think he wants the first tuple to be 5,7, the second to be 10,13.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you want to accomplish (because I had the same problem)!

Why not use complex numbers because they are basically nothing else but two dimensional numbers and they are an official data type in R with all the necessary methods available:

```
A <- complex(real=5,imaginary=10) 
B <- complex(real=7,imaginary=13)

c(A,B)
## [1] 5+10i 7+13i

matrix(c(A,B),ncol=1)
##       [,1]
## [1,] 5+10i
## [2,] 7+13i
```