# Looping over multiple lists with base R

Tags: r

In python we can do this..

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
characters = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

for item in zip(numbers, characters):
    print(item[0], item[1])

(1, 'foo')
(2, 'bar')
(3, 'baz')
```

We can also unpack the tuple rather than using the index.

```
for num, char in zip(numbers, characters):
    print(num, char)

(1, 'foo')
(2, 'bar')
(3, 'baz')
```

How can we do the same using base R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating tuples from two vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799591/creating-tuples-from-two-vectors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do something like this in an R-native way, you'd use the idea of a data frame. A data frame has multiple variables which can be of different types, and each row is an observation of each variable.

```
d <- data.frame(numbers = c(1, 2, 3),
                characters = c('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
d
##   numbers characters
## 1       1        foo
## 2       2        bar
## 3       3        baz
```

You then access each row using matrix notation, where leaving an index blank includes everything.

```
d[1,]
##   numbers characters
## 1       1        foo
```

You can then loop over the rows of the data frame to do whatever you want to do, presumably you actually want to do something more interesting than printing.

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(d))) {
  print(d[i,])
}
##   numbers characters
## 1       1        foo
##   numbers characters
## 2       2        bar
##   numbers characters
## 3       3        baz
```

Comment: A drive-by downvoting with no comment? Not cool. Come on out of the shadows and help improve the answer!

Comment: I did not downvote but what you do here is better achieved with an apply function imho?

Answer (score 5):

For another option, how about `mapply`, which is the closest analog to zip I can think of in R. Here I'm using the `c` function to make a new vector, but you could use any function you'd like:

```
numbers<- c(1, 2, 3)
characters<-  c('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
mapply(c,numbers, characters, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

[[1]]
[1] "1"   "foo"

[[2]]
[1] "2"   "bar"

[[3]]
[1] "3"   "baz"
```

Which way is of most use depends on what you want to do with your output, but as the other answers mention, a dataframe is the most natural approach in R (and pandas dataframe probably in python).

Answer (score 3):

To index a vector in R, where the vector is variable `x` would be x[1]. This would return the first element of the vector. R element numbering starts at 1 in contrast to Python which starts at 0.

For this problem it would be:

```
x = seq(1,10)
j = seq(11,20)

for (i in 1:length(x)){

    print (c(x[i],j[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Many functions in R are vectorized and don't require loops:

```
numbers = c(1, 2, 3)
characters = c('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
myList <- list(numbers, characters)
myDF <- data.frame(numbers,characters, stringsAsFactors = F)

print(myList)
print(myDF)
```

Answer (score 1):

Other scalable alternatives: Store the vectors in the list and iterate over.

```
vect1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
vect1 <- c('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
vect2 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')


idx_list <- list(vect1, vect2)
idx_vect <- c(1:length(idx_list[[1]]))

for(i in idx_vect){
    x <- idx_list[[1]][i]
    j <- idx_list[[2]][i]
    print(c(i, x, j))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the conceptual equivalent:

```
for (item in Map(list,numbers,characters)){ # though most of the time you would actually do all your work inside Map
  print(item[c(1,2)])
}

# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b"
# 
# [[1]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "c"
# 
# [[1]]
# [1] 4
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "d"
# 
# [[1]]
# [1] 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "e"
```

Though most of the time you would actually do all your work inside Map and do something like this:

```
Map(function(nu,ch){print(data.frame(nu,ch))},numbers,characters)
```

This is the closest I could get to a clone:

```
zip <- function(...){ Map(list,...)}
print2 <- function(...){do.call(cat,c(list(...),"\n"))}

for (item in zip(numbers,characters)){
  print2(item[[1]],item[[2]])
}

# 1 a 
# 2 b 
# 3 c 
# 4 d 
# 5 e
```

to be able to call items by their names (still works with indices):

```
zip <- function(...){
  names <- sapply(substitute(list(...))[-1],deparse)
  Map(function(...){setNames(list(...),names)}, ...)
}

for (item in zip(numbers,characters)){
  print2(item[["numbers"]],item[["characters"]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tidyverse solution would be to use `purrr::map2` function. Ex:

```
numbers <- c(1, 2, 3)
characters <- c('foo', 'bar', 'baz')

map2(numbers, characters, ~paste0(.x, ',', .y))

#[[1]]
#[1] "1,foo"

#[[2]]
#[1] "2,bar"

#[[3]]
#[1] "3,baz"
```

See API [here](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html)