# Define a vector with sequence in R

Tags: r

I would like to create a sequence of theta (1,100),(2,100),(3,100)...(100,100)

`theta[1]` is `seq(from = 1 , to = 100 , length =100)`

`theta[2]` is `1`

How should I define theta?

Comment: you mean, `theta[2]` is `100`?

Comment: What do you mean by "theta[2] is 1"? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799591/creating-tuples-from-two-vectors

Comment: `Map(':', 1:100, 100)` or `Map(c, 1:100, 100)`, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are just looking for a matrix somehow, or a data.frame. I guess you actually want `theta[2] = 100` to make sense. So

```
 theta = matrix(c(seq(1,100),rep(1,100)),nrow = 100,ncol = 2)
```

will give you the pair in each row theta[n,], and from your definition `theta[1]` will now be `theta[,1]`, `theta[2]` will be `theta[,2]`

Comment: Thank you for your answers:) I would like to ask that if I want to fix theta[2] and make theta[1] from 1 to 100, and let theta be the argument of a function to plot. In plot, theta[1] is x coordinate and function(theta) is the corresponding y coordinate, how can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just create your two sequences, and row-bind them:

```
theta = rbind(seq(from=1, to=100, length=100), rep(100,100))
```

Now your `theta` will look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] ...
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    13    14 ...
[2,]  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100  100   100   100   100   100   100 ...
```

and `theta[1,]` will be a sequence from 1 to 100, and `theta[2,]` a sequence of all 100s of size 100.

Comment: Thank you for your answers:) I would like to ask that if I want to fix theta[2] and make theta[1] from 1 to 100, and let theta be the argument of a function to plot. In plot, theta[1] is x coordinate and function(theta) is the corresponding y coordinate, how can I do this? Thanks

Comment: @Yifan your question is not very clear to me. If you fix your y coordinate and let the x coordinates vary from 1 to 100, you'll get a horizontal line at y=100. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I mean, for example, I have the theta above and a function f(z). In f, only z(1) will be used, and now I want to plot the function f as the y coordinate and theta (1,) be the x coordinate, how should I do it? f takes theta as the argument.Thanks.